# Adding check boxes dynamically to multiple fragment layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-checkbox

I am trying to create check boxes dynamically according to the data obtained from a database, up to a maximum of 6 in a single fragment, and if there are more than 6 then they're shown in the next fragment and so on...

Here's the code I've got so far:

```
for(int i=0;i<size; i+=2){
        RelativeLayout rl=new RelativeLayout(CreateFuelOnlyInspectionActivity.this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        int rlMarginTop_px = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        lp.topMargin=rlMarginTop_px;
        rl.setLayoutParams(lp);

        CheckBox cb1=new CheckBox(CreateFuelOnlyInspectionActivity.this);
        cb1.setId(1);
        cb1.setTag(""+i);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams cbParams1=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        cb1.setLayoutParams(cbParams1);
        cb1.setButtonDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox_selector));
        rl.addView(cb1);
```

But this only handles a single fragment. How can I extend this to more?

Comment: why do you want to use fragment. please specific more about your usecase so we can help

Comment: actually i am using that in viewapger concept.I have a viewpager with three fragments or screens and in screen 2  i have a innerviewpager(childviewpager) which consists of fragments again..so when first fragment in innerviewpager is filled with 6 check boxes,swipe should be enabled and move to second fragment and in second fragment the leftout check boxes must be visible.

Answer (score 0):

put your code like:

```
    RelativeLayout rl=new RelativeLayout(CreateFuelOnlyInspectionActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    int rlMarginTop_px = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    lp.topMargin=rlMarginTop_px;
    rl.setLayoutParams(lp);

    CheckBox cb1;

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams cbParams1=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    for(int i=0;i<=6; i++){

        cb1=new CheckBox(CreateFuelOnlyInspectionActivity.this);
        cb1.setId(i);
        cb1.setTag(""+i);
        cb1.setLayoutParams(cbParams1);
        cb1.setButtonDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox_selector));
        rl.addView(cb1);
    }       
// enable view page here
```